# python: Check status of thread by ID

Tags: python, multithreading

I have a multithreading Python(2.7) program, which runs multiple threads for different tasks. I am storing the thread-ids, for tracking the status of threads in a separate thread for status-tracking.

How can I check the thread is alive or not ( `isAlive()` ) by having the thread-id ?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, I don't believe there's a way to retrieve the thread by its thread_id. Your best bet would be to store a reference to the thread object itself.

Comment: Exactly. [threading.get_ident()](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/threading.html#threading.get_ident) returns a meaningless integer that can not be used to retrieve the thread instance.

Comment: I'm also facing the same issue, @remis if got the solution please let us know

Answer (score 1):

You can get a list of all active Threads by [threading.enumerate()](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/threading.html#threading.enumerate) (for Python 3: [threading.enumerate()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.enumerate))

> Return a list of all Thread objects currently active.

And then check if this list contains Thread with stored id. If yes - the thread is still alive.

As example:

```py
import threading

t_id = 1080 # stored thread id
is_alive = any([th for th in threading.enumerate() if th.ident == t_id])

print("Still alive: ", is_alive)
```