# Check the status of a running async ansible playbook using Python Flask API

Tags: python, ansible

In a Flask API I have an endpoint able to run an ansible playbook on remote host using:

```
ansible_runner.run_async
```

The playbook is running for long time and I would like to allow my users to check playbook status using another endpoint.

How is this possible if the only data I have is the job id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to run another playbook that invokes the [async_status](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/async_status_module.html) module to poll the status of the required job ID. Basically, the async job status is being stored just as a temporary file (`~/.ansible_async/<job_id>` by default):

```json
{"started": 1, "finished": 0, "ansible_job_id": "j822597927077.20367"}
```

Comment: This is indeed correct but how do I get the job_id from the 1st playbook?

Comment: In the original question you've mentioned that you have the job id, so I supposed that your API response has it. If not, when you run an Ansible task in async mode, its return object will have the `ansible_job_id` parameter.

Comment: Would you mind sharing how? If I don't collect thread.join() (and wait) I can't seem to find it...

Comment: Initially I thought that you are able a get return object with `job_id` from a task [running in async mode](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_async.html#asynchronous-playbook-tasks). You can still go that way and adjust the task in your playbook. But since you seem to have a `Thread` object and (more likely) aren't able to store a reference to it, you can save its ID using `get_ident()` and then check for its presence in `threading.enumerate()` list of active threads. Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71179393/16417367) for details.